# Get parameters from running workflow

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, workflow-foundation-4

I have been looking at the WF Wizard examples on endpoint.tv and here:
http://stevenalexander.posterous.com/integrating-a-persisted-wf40-workflow-with-mv

I want to be able to use a WF to drive the wizard, but also to act as a temporary store for incomplete wizards.  This means that for each step of the wizard I dont persist the data, until the end of the workflow, when all data has been entered.

I have a basic example which is almost working, based on the link above that works by:

1. Creates and persists a new workflow
2. //user then navigates to first wizard step//
3. WF is resumed, a model is passed to the BookMarkCallback
4. The WFs global collection of models is updated.
5. The WF then moves to he next step, if the user chose next.

However, the problem is that although the WF is saving data, I cannot see a way to retrieve the data mid way.  i.e. if the user reloads step 1, I dont know how I can get that persisted model back to the user.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok.. for anyone else..

I resolved this by using my own "Notification" extension, which has a Notification event handler as such:

```
public class HostEventNotifier : IHostNotification
{
    public event EventHandler<HostNotifyEventArgs> Notification;

    public void Notify(object model)
    {
        if(Notification != null)
        {
            Notification(this, new HostNotifyEventArgs(model));

        }
    }
}
```

The extension was added to the WF application and could be called in my wizard eventsteps as:

```
 var ext = context.GetExtension<IHostNotification>();
        var parentModel = context.GetValue(ParentModel);
        if(ext!=null && parentModel !=null)
        {
            if(parentModel.ContainsKey(bookmarkName))
            {
                ext.Notify(parentModel[bookmarkName]);
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }

        }
```

Finaly the extension event handler was set to a method that knew how to handle my data.

This is still incomplete - I havent worked out the threading model (hence the uglt Thread.Sleep) but I wanted to give an answer to anyone else looking.

The idea for this came from "Pro WF 4/ Bukovics", apress